# Dynamically Populate Select List in jqGrid Add Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

I am using 4.13.3 - free jqGrid.

I have two select lists in my add form. In the first lists I fire a dataevent that runs ajax call and returns html code of select list tag.

I would like to change the second select list to this html code. I get the htlm code on the call back but the second select list does not change to returned code.

here is a code snipt:

```
function biAddForm(formId){

        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('groupno', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/ShippingDocumentControllerServletV7?lifecycle=groupnolist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('boeingcontract', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});       
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('shippertype', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/ShippingDocumentControllerServletV7?lifecycle=shippertypelist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('shippertype', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {shipperscopeconfig(this.value);  }}]}});
        //$("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('shipperscope', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/ShippingDocumentControllerServletV7?lifecycle=shipperscopelist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('ife', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('greinercushions', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('retroshipment', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});        
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('requires8130', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});     
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('delegationflag', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/ShippingDocumentControllerServletV7?lifecycle=shipperyesnoonlylist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('embraer', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});      
        $("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('dsaflag', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/GenericControllerServlet?lifecycle=threewayoptionlist'}});      

    };
    function shipperscopeconfig(shiptype){
        alert("shipperscopeconfig: " + shiptype);
        switch(parseInt(shiptype)){

        case 3:

            break;

        default:
            alert("Running Default");
            $.post("/QMSWebApp/ShippingDocumentControllerServletV7",
            {lifecycle:"shipperscopelist"}, scResults, 'JSON');

            break;

        }

    }
    function scResults(wResults){
        alert(wResults.selstmt);
        $('#shipperscope').html(wResults.selstmt);

    }
```

Comment: is this correct: you need to show some info in the 2nd select according to what you select in the 1st, correct? now, what do you see when you do `console.log(wResults.selstmt)`?

Comment: Yes this is what I need. I could not get the console.log to push anything to the console. However, the alert does show the proper html. I did discover if I change $('#shipperscope').html(wResults.selstmt); to $('#tr_shipperscope').html(wResults.selstmt); I do get a populated list but I has lost all formatting. Can I change just the list portion of the $('#tr_shipperscope') content?

Comment: is there no way to use this(what I had before until I discovered that it is based on the ship type value)$("#shippingdocsqueue").setColProp('shipperscope', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/ShippingDocumentControllerServletV7?lifecycle=shipperscopelist'}}); after the dataevent fires from the ship type?

Comment: you need to show the structure of `wResults.selstmt` so we can help, basically you could take that info into parts and give each to each `option` tag in your select, but without knowing what `wResults.selstmt` contains, that is as concrete as I can get

Comment: Got the console to work: <select><option value=0></option><option value=1 disabled>Full(Disabled. No Blue Tag  No Mechanical Conformity Checklist)</option><option value=2>Partial</option><option value=3 disabled>Final(Disabled. No Blue Tag  No Mechanical Conformity Checklist)</option></select>

Comment: This works as desired: $('#tr_shipperscope select').append(wr[i]); Thanks for all the help.